# MongoError: some query field is only allowed as the first pipeline stage but it is the first stage

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```js
await WishlistItem.aggregate([
          { $match: { $text: { $search: 'itemName' } } },
]);
```

gives me `$match with $text is only allowed as the first pipeline stage`

But it is the first and only  stage.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `mongoose-delete` library on this model.

```js
itemSchema.plugin(mongoose_delete, {
  indexFields: ['deletedAt'],
  overrideMethods: 'all',
  validateBeforeDelete: false,
});
```

I had to use `aggregateWithDeleted` instead of `aggregate`. Seems like `mongoose-delete` adds a stage to the pipeline to remove soft deleted documents.

```js
await WishlistItem.aggregateWithDeleted([
          { $match: { $text: { $search: 'itemName' } } },
]);
```